# Stuck in infinite loop C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop

I have a problem that when I  want to scroll the program freezes and have to close it. I think the problem is that the system falls in an infinite loop and crash(bacause of run out of memory i think). Here is the code where the while is:

```
string acorde;
int ScrollPosition = this.vScrollBar1.Value;
if (ScrollPosition < 5)
{
    acorde = "A";
    lblnota.Text = "A/La";
    lblnota2.Text = "A/La";
    imagen.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\A.jpg");

    while(note != 1)
    {
        lblnote.Text = "A";
        lblcuerda.Text = "5° cuerda";
        lbltraste.Text = "";
        imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
    }
    imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\OK.jpg");
    while(note != 8)
    {
        lblnote.Text = "E";
        lblcuerda.Text = "4° cuerda";
        lbltraste.Text = "2° traste";
        imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
    }
    imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\OK.jpg");
    while(note != 1)
    {
        lblnote.Text = "A";
        lblcuerda.Text = "3° cuerda";
        lbltraste.Text = "2° traste";
        imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
    }
    imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\OK.jpg");
    while (note != 5)
    {
        lblnote.Text = "C#";
        lblcuerda.Text = "2° cuerda";
        lbltraste.Text = "2° traste";
        imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
    }
    imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\OK.jpg");

    while (note != 8)
    {
        lblnote.Text = "E";
        lblcuerda.Text = "1° cuerda";
        lbltraste.Text = "";
        imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
    }
    imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\OK.jpg");


}
else if (ScrollPosition < 12)
{
    lblnota.Text = "Am/Lam";
    lblnota2.Text = "Am/Lam";
    imagen.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\A#.jpg");
```

I really need your help right  now. Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `if` instead of all those `while`?

Comment: the `note` value never changes, so you will never exit the `while` loops

Comment: Try using your debugger...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is your use of `while` loops.

```
while(note != 1)
```

There is nothing in the body of those loops that change that condition. So everytime the loop goes "okay... is note not equal to 1?".. that condition is always true. So the loop executes again.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you are stuck in infinite loop.

you are checking for `note != 1` or other comparisons but I don't see `note` being changed in any of those `while` loops.

Once you get into one of those loops you'll never exit as `note` will always have same value.

following is what your code should look like.

```
if (ScrollPosition < 5)
        {
            acorde = "A";
            lblnota.Text = "A/La";
            lblnota2.Text = "A/La";
            imagen.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\A.jpg");

        if(note != 1)
        {
            lblnote.Text = "A";
            lblcuerda.Text = "5° cuerda";
            lbltraste.Text = "";
            imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
        }
        else if(note != 8)
        {
            lblnote.Text = "E";
            lblcuerda.Text = "4° cuerda";
            lbltraste.Text = "2° traste";
            imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
        }
        else if(note != 1)
        {
            lblnote.Text = "A";
            lblcuerda.Text = "3° cuerda";
            lbltraste.Text = "2° traste";
            imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
        }
        else if(note != 5)
        {
            lblnote.Text = "C#";
            lblcuerda.Text = "2° cuerda";
            lbltraste.Text = "2° traste";
            imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
        }
        else if(note != 8)
        {
            lblnote.Text = "E";
            lblcuerda.Text = "1° cuerda";
            lbltraste.Text = "";
            imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\MAL.jpg");
        }
        imagenok.Image = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Users\Sebastian\Desktop\GuitarraFINAL\Guitarist\Imagenes\OK.jpg");
    }
```

Comment: It should be noted that there are two `!= 1` conditions here.. only one of which (the first) will ever be executed.